# Debugging an obfuscated .NET core application with DotPeek

Tags: asp.net-core, obfuscation, computer-forensics, dotpeek

I am hunting for a possible **logic bomb** in the code deployed to production by our vendor software factory.

For sake of **curiosity** of the readers, here is a brief recap. The application stopped working with an infinite wait at some point. Decompiling the obfuscated code, I found an odd `Thread.sleep` that should never be in an MVC API, where the amount is computed by difference of the current ticks to a value computed *somehow*. I.e.

```
private long SomeFunction(long param) {
    if (param > 0)
        Thread.Sleep(param);
    return param;
}

private long GetSomeLongValue() {
    //Simplified. There is a lot of long to string and back
    return SomeFunction(Manipulate(DateTime.Now.Ticks - GetMysteryNumber()));
}

private long Manipulate(long param){
    if (param < 0)
        return param;
    else
        # Compute a random number of days between 0 and param / 86400000,
        # and return its milliseconds value, always positive
}
```

And by running experiments with system clock, I found that there is a **magic** `DateTime.Now` value when the application works (before) and stops (right after one second). The experiment was consistent and repeatable.

**Back to the question**

I have done all this work using [JetBrains DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). This was done by looking at the code: human static analysis.

The problem is that what I have called `SomeMysteryFunction` is too well obfuscated that I really can't get any clue about what it does. I have the full code but I would like to take another approach.

I'd like to **exercise** that function and **try** to see if it returns consistent values that **may** be equal to the guilty timestamp. The function depends on the result of `GetCallingAssembly` method, so that will be a pain in the back.

I thought about running some sort of `Program.cs` or unit test that exploits the obfuscated function by reflection, but I'd like to debug using DotPeek. Why?

- Disassembly can be a mess
- I tried Telerik, but I had a lot more success with DotPeek decompiling async methods **not in** their StateMachine representation

I have never done this in my work experience. I just need to be sure about this being intentional or not.

How do I set up a test bed environment so that I can debug into a linked DLL decompiled by DotPeek?

Comment: Gave you tried running it through De4Dot?

Answer (score 2):

This post [In the Jungle of .NET Decompilers](https://blog.ndepend.com/in-the-jungle-of-net-decompilers/) explains all .NET Decompilers that are worth to use.

Definitely the [free and OSS tool dnSpy](https://github.com/dnSpyEx/dnSpy) is the one you want to use for that sort of *hacking[I'd like to exercise that function]* scenarios.